# What is the dimension and basis of this space?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have a vector space

$$
k_1(1,0,0) + k_2 (2,-3,1)
$$

I know the basis is {(1,0,0), (2,-3,1)} and the dimension of this vector space is 2.

But what if I have a space

$$
(1,0,0) + k_2 (2,-3,1)
$$

What will be the basis and dimension of this space? Is it the same? Certainly the basis cant be {(1,0,0)} or {(2,-3,1)} as we can't get the one from the other by simple scalar multiplication.

Comment: It is not a vector space, but an affine space, with direction generated by $(2,-3,1)$ (hence an affine space of dimension $1$).

Comment: Oh I see, this basically represents a line in 3D that does not pass through origin. Thank you.